symfony "fileperms() stat failed for" error
I work on an application with symfony and upgrade it from 5.4 version to 6.4.
Since, I can't cache:clear without to get many errors :
With cache:clear -vvv I get :
07:40:33 DEBUG     [php] Warning: fileperms(): stat failed for "lot of path"

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 61440 bytes) in 

It seems I have a problem with permission but I can't find what is the problem.
Application is located in the www folder of wamp64 in windows.
PATH : C:\wamp64\www\vhs202405

I generated a virtualhost based on my application.
PATH : C:\wamp64\www\vhs202405\public

I hadn't any problem before.
I found this to avoid error about the memory size but it does not correct the problem :
php -d memory_limit = -1 bin/console cache:clear


It might be necessary to manually delete the cache, probably in C:\wamp64\www\vhs202405\var\cache
If you upgrade Symfony without first clearing the cache, the console and the cache:clear command may fail completely.  This is a known problem and was recently added to the upgrade instructions.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/upgrade_major.html

A best practice after updating to a new major version is to clear the cache. Instead of running the cache:clear command (which won't work if the application is not bootable in the console after the upgrade) it's better to remove the entire cache directory contents:
rm -rf var/cache/*
rmdir /s /q var\cache*

